# iCloud, iCloudKit, iOS 8, Apple id

Tags: ios, icloud

As I understand it now can not get apple id in iOS 7. 
iOS 8 has many edits to work with iCloud and adding iCloudKit. Will I be able to get Apple id from API and use it, for example, for registration in own server?

Comment: Seriously doubt it, would be a pretty easy way to steal someones apple id

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot get the user's Apple ID.

What you *can* do with CloudKit is get an opaque user record ID. This object will be the same for the user for your app on all of their devices, but it will be different for other apps or other users. You can save that on your server and use it as something like a "log in with CloudKit" feature. This was described in the WWDC 2014 intro to CloudKit session. Basically, you use the `fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler:` method on `CKContainer`. But there's no way to link this to the Apple ID automatically-- you still need to ask the user if you want that.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of. That's kind of "invading" the user's privacy because you'd be getting his Apple ID (which is an email) without his consent.

What I do, using Parse SDK, is to make the user log in anonimously at my Parse App, then save his automatically generated User ID in a iCloud Key-Value container. Whenever the user deletes the app and reinstalls it (or simply install in another device of his), my app knows that he has an username saved on iCloud and then uses that instead of creating a new user. This way, I get to keep track of my users without invading nobody's privacy.